# Pegar posições de uma palavra dentro de um texto

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho um texto e quero pegar as posições iniciais de uma palavra específica em todas as ocorrências dentro desse texto. Por exemplo, tenho o seguinte texto:

```
maria gosta de joão. jose gosta de maria. maria gosta de joao e jose.
```

Notem que a palavra "**maria**" possui 3 ocorrências. Se eu usasse `indexOf("maria")`, o resultado seria `0`, porque o `indexOf` pega apenas a primeira ocorrência. Só que o `indexOf` não pega a posição de todas as ocorrências, apenas a primeira e a última com `lastIndexOf`.

O que eu queria era obter a posição das 3 palavras "maria", que no texto acima seriam:

```
maria gosta de joão. jose gosta de maria. maria gosta de joao e jose.
↑                                  ↑      ↑
0                                  35     42
```

Eu conseguiria fazer isso percorrendo todo o texto, caractere por caractere, mas se o texto for muito extenso, não vejo assim uma boa maneira.

Que técnica eficiente ou melhor eu poderia usar para obter esse resultado? Talvez um regex?

Comment: você quer evitar o loop com substring?

Comment: Eu preferia porque se o texto for muito grande, fica meio tabajara. Pode até usar um loop em algum momento, mas queria uma forma mais eficiente.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Uma forma simples de construir o resultado que pretende é utilizar também o segundo parâmetro do [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) que lhe permite indicar a partir de onde faz a procura.

Da [documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf):

> arr.indexOf(searchElement[, fromIndex])

Assim inicialmente começa a partir do `0`, e nas subsequentes chamadas começa onde tinha terminado anteriormente, acabando com `-1` que é quando já não tem mais.

Exemplo:

```js
let texto = "maria gosta de joão. jose gosta de maria. maria gosta de joao e jose.",
    procura = "maria",
    posicoes = [],
    posicaoCorrente = texto.indexOf(procura);

while (posicaoCorrente != -1) {
  posicoes.push(posicaoCorrente);
  posicaoCorrente = texto.indexOf(procura, posicaoCorrente + procura.length);
}

console.log(posicoes);
```

Comment: Verdade. Esqueci que o indexOf possui um segundo parâmetro. Tô com problema de memória sério. Obg!

Comment: @dvd Sem problema, estamos cá todos para ajudar :). É fácil um pormenor desses passar despercebido.

Comment: @Isac, Boa, eu nem sabia que tinha esse overload e ia postar a resposta quebrando com substring como havia comentado na pergunta.

Comment: @LeandroAngelo Posta a sua resposta também. Toda resposta válida é bem vinda, não importa se seja a melhor (quem sabe?).